# File rename regex adding unwanted suffix

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I have a problem with `rename -v 's/\.jpg$/\_120x120.jpg/' *.jpg`

`zzr31_120x120.jpg` renamed as `zzr31_120x120_120x120.jpg`

How can I make it more clear that it would rename only those that don't have 120х120?
And on top of that to make it not only `jpg` but for `gif` and `png` in one command if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and use the regexp to match the extensions of your choices, making rename consider every file with just *

so anyway, this is my proposal

```
rename -n 's/^((?:(?!_120x120).)*)\.(jpg|png|gif)$/$1_120x120.$2/' *
```

remove the -n to make it functional, otherwise it will only show what it will rename and won't actually rename

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something called `negative look-behind assertions`; check the `perlre(1)` documentation for full details. I'm having trouble coming up with the exact syntax to use, this was my last effort:

```
/(.*)\K120x120\.(jpg|gif|png)/$1_120x120.$2/
```

An easier answer is to move away the "good" files first:

```
mkdir foo
mv *_120x120.* foo
rename -v 's/\.jpg$/\_120x120.jpg/' *.jpg
mv foo/* .
rmdir foo
```